# adding location as subdirectory to url with mod rewrite?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, subdirectory

I working on project that displays item according to the location. First time user has to pick a location in order to search for an item. This location is saved as cookie for future reference. The url looks as following:

```
 www.example.com/newyork
```

If the user is looking at an item that exists in New York, the url for that item is:

```
 www.example.com/item/iphone
```

Above url works fine but there is one problem. If the above url is forwarded through an email to a first time user, This item does not exist because the location is not selected. I could forward user to different page to select location and then look for the item, but this is hassle for the user. So, I would like to change above url to

```
 www.example.com/newyork/item/iphone
```

so that way I could use New York as location. How do I add a non-existing sub directory to a url? Canthis be done with PHP or done with mod_rewrite?

Comment: You can make `www.example.com/newyork/item/iphone` rewrite to `www.example.com/item/iphone` but what happens to the "newyork" part? You said it was supposed to be in a cookie?

Comment: well, nothing happens to "newyork" part, it just stays in cookie for future reference. Main reason I am trying to do this is to better serve email links or forwards. If the link only provides [link](www.example.com/item/iphone), Its impossible to tell where the user location is(unless I forward user to different page to pick location). Whereas if the link already has location [link](www.example.com/newyork/item/iphone),  then we can serve first time user with asking them the location. This situation mostly applies to forwarded or emailed links. Hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: But if someone goes to `www.example.com/newyork/item/iphone` link from an email, and it gets rewritten so that `/item/iphone` gets served, how does `/item/iphone` know what the location is, there's no cookie yet because they clicked a link from an email.

Comment: You are correct. Can you suggest any solution. All I am trying to create is to add location to link so that way I would know where exact the item is located or listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing a redirect, but you'll have to carefully craft the regular expression used to match `/newyork/item/iphone`. Then you can group out the `newyork` part and set a cookie and redirect the browser using the `CO` flag.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/item/([^/]+)$ /item/$2 [L,R,CO=location:$1:example.com:/]
```

This will take a request like `http://www.example.com/pittsburgh/item/iphone` and extract the `pittsburgh` part, store it in a cookie named `location` (with the domain=example.com and path=/), then redirect the browser so the cookie gets stored by the browser and make the browser go to `http://www.example.com/item/iphone`

See the [documentation for the `CO` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_co) for details about the syntax:

```
[CO=NAME:VALUE:DOMAIN:lifetime:path:secure:httponly]
```

---

> Quick question. The acutal link without mod_rewrite rule is `www.example.com/item.php/itemid=phone`. Is it possible to rewrite this link to `www.example.com/newyork/item.php/itemid=phone`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/item.php/itemid=(.+)$ /item.php/itemid=$2 [L,R,CO=location:$1:example.com:/]
```